# How to properly use MPAndroidChart LineChart and selection listener?

Tags: android, linechart, mpandroidchart

I use [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) for my project, it's a line chart. I want to achieve when I select the value, the circle stands for the value changes it's color to be red, when I `onNothingSelected`, it's color is blue. The following is my code:

```
mLineChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
            lineDataSet.setCircleColor(Color.RED);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {
            lineDataSet.setCircleColor(Color.rgb(26, 115, 197));

        }
    });
```

If I do like that, when I select the value, all of circle is red. How can I do for what I want to achieve?
[image: when I select one value,all value is red]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no option to style a single entry in a dataset object.

A solution can be to create an empty data set that has the styling of your choice, and upon clicking an entry, you add that entry to the data set.

Comment: Can you please have a look on this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/39589620/1503130